# My PHP session values not updating automatically

Tags: php, variables, session

I have just created a login and profile update system in PHP:

```php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_login_process)) {
    $db_user_name       = $row['user_name'];
    $db_user_first_name = $row['user_firstname'];
    $db_user_last_name  = $row['user_lastname'];
    $db_user_email      = $row['user_email'];
    $db_user_password   = $row['user_password'];
    $db_user_content    = $row['user_content'];
    $db_user_role       = $row['user_role'];
}

if($user_email === $db_user_email && $user_password === $db_user_password && $db_user_role = "Admin") {
    $_SESSION['user_name']      = $db_user_name;
    $_SESSION['user_firstname'] = $db_user_first_name;
    $_SESSION['user_lastname']  = $db_user_last_name;
    $_SESSION['user_email']     = $db_user_email;
    $_SESSION['user_role']      = $db_user_role;
    header("Location: admin/");
}
```

In the code above I fetched data from a database and stored them in `$_SESSION` variables for later use. 
If the user updates their profile all of the session variables data should be updated to match.

After successfully updating their profile it will also update in the database. But previously I stored variables like `username`, and `email`  in session variables, and they are not updating with the new data from the database, they remain the old values.

```php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
    $user_letter = strtoupper($_SESSION['user_name']);
    $user_name   = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $user_email  = $_SESSION['user_email'];
}
```

How can I update session variables after updating changes in database?

Comment: Do you execute `session_start();` before any other output?

Comment: Where is the code that is supposed to change the values of the session variables after an update?

Comment: the code block of while should execute twice, first on user login and second on profile update too.Also I believe that your query return single record every time so no need to use while.

Comment: As @Zhorov mentions -> session_start() is needed. Both for reading from and writing to session variables.

Comment: Can you update your question and show how are you updating your database and storing session?